# Unable to retrieve node content with drupalgap

Tags: javascript

I've set up drupalgap on my website, followed all the instructions and got the Hello World example up and running via Ripple.  I've also been able to adapt that example to put a new logo and different menus on the front page.  However, when I try and view node content it just hangs, with "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" being reported via the console.  I've not written any code of my own to do this, I'm just trying to access nodes via the top-left menu provided in the tutorial example.

I've made sure the node entity type is enabled in the services.  I can view user entities (and if I disable these then I get a 404 so enabling nodes doesn't appear to be the issue.

So I've taken it back to basics and if I navigate to example.com/user/1/json I get the page I expect and likewise for example.com/node/1/json.  However when I use example.com/?q=drupalgap/node/1.json I get a blank screen, whereas for example.com/?q=drupalgap/user/1.json I get the JSON output for that user.  So I am concluding that for some reason nodes are not being output via drupalgap (returning null instead?) whereas users are.

Any clues?

David

Comment: Something (contrib module, custom module, contrib theme) is interfering with the retrieval of node JSON data. There are a few common culprits listed here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2015065

Comment: Thanks for that - if nothing else it is comforting to know I was kind of looking in the right places: I'd come across that linked page and thought that may well be a factor.  It definitely isn't one of the listed culprits as I have none of those installed but I'll try turning off modules until I find the real culprit!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with thanks to the advice about it being another module interfering with the retrieval of JSON data, I've identified the culprit through a process of elimination.

When I disable the "Node Registration" module the problem goes away and I can view node content through the mobile app.

Of course, that gives me another problem with how to get the functionality Node Registration was giving me, but I'll save that one for now...